# I am using React Router v6 but my routing is not happening

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import News from './components/News'
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar/>
        <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<News Key=":general" pageSize={15} country="in" category= "general"/>} />
        <Route end path="/business"element={<News Key=":business" pageSize={15} country="in" category= "business"/>} />
        <Route path="/entertainment" element={<News Key=":entertainment" pageSize={15} country="in" category= "entertainment"/>} />
        <Route path="/general" element={<News Key=":general" pageSize={15} country="in" category= "general"/> }/>
        <Route path="/health" element={<News Key=":health" pageSize={15} country="in" category= "health"/>} />
        <Route path="/science" element={<News Key=":science" pageSize={15} country="in" category= "science"/>} />
        <Route path="/sports" element={<News Key=":sports" pageSize={15} country="in" category= "sports"/>} />
        <Route path="/technology" element={<News Key=":technology" pageSize={15} country="in" category= "technology"/>} />
        
        </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Dude, I am really against giving bad points to someone new, but there are so many things that can go wrong. Do some of the URLs work or all of them?. What is this ":" in the Key, you want to use dynamic routing?  This "Key" is with capital K, is it a component?.
If you need assistance rephrasing your quest,I will be happy to help.

Comment: So, ***other than*** "it's not working" what exactly is the issue? Are there any error messages in the console? What are you doing to validate that the routing isn't happening? Can you explain in better detail what that actually means?

Comment: HI @DrewReese, The issue is when I am trying to click on my any of the above route, its not going to page where it should go. No I am not getting any error in console. I have several navbar option as mentioned above, my intention is to click on those item and it should route me to the appropriate page.

Comment: You don't click on routes, they are non-interactable components. What are you clicking on? Please include all relevant code and details *in your question*. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

your import should be like this :

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and use the Router instead of BrowserRouter

also add **exact** keyword inside every route before the path

Comment: It is not necessary to `import BrowserRouter as Router`, also react router v6 doesn't have exact prop

Comment: @Inder i am using react router v6 and there is exact keyword

Comment: Checkout these [Docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#relative-routes-and-links) . Passing a prop doesn't cause any errors, that doesn't mean its supported

Comment: i didn't know that but the weird case is that i am using react router dom v6 and i have to use exact to be able to use the exact path

Comment: @RazorJhon I have used exact keyword also but that is also not working. According to docs exact is not required in version6

Comment: maybe that Key prop is the issue ? can you provide the error you are getting ? if its a white page then something in your props is wrong , try to debug the code by create a text and remove News component and see if the links is wrong or not , if its working then something wrong with your props

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the preceding answer fixes things for you.  If it doesn't, I do recall a colleague at another company in Silicon Valley telling me about 6 months ago that they tried upgrading to React Router v6 but it just didn't work for them so that had to revert back to v5.

Answer (score 0):

Just crosscheck your News component because that is causing the issue
here as
routing part is fine. Try the below code and change the paths, the
component as
per path will be shown, which means your routing part is fine, only news
component is wrong somewhere
[image: Routing working fine]

```
Hope it solved your query!
```